# allow user to enter mkannotation name swift ios

Tags: ios, swift, mkannotation

I've seen numerous posts on how to customize `MKPointAnnotation` but what I'd like to learn about is how to let a user enter a name for a dropped pin in an app. So, rather than having a predefined `array` of names, say for restaurants, etc., when the pin is dropped, the user could enter their own name for a location, such as `the best pizza in Chicago` or `my favorite spot to photograph sunrises` and so on.

Any ideas on this?

Thanks!

Comment: as a start you can do that by handling the clicks on the pin and then showing a view for accepting the input then on confirm update the pin.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Is there an example or tutorial on how to do this anywhere?

Comment: Check out Paul Hagerty's mapkit tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4E5K_UGybOo I believe what you want starts ~19min into the video. Have fun.